# In Facebook, Groups is missing from "more" menu. How can I return it?

Tags: facebook

It was the case that when I went to More, I saw Groups (see pic headed "first")

I was trying to hide groups from public view..   I didn't and don't see Groups in "more....manage sections". (see pic headed "second")

A guy I spoke to suggested to click Groups and click on the pencil icon and to click "hide section". I did that and now the section is hidden from me, and not showing under More,  (see pic headed "third")  and still not showing in 'manage sections'.

How can I  at least return "Groups" to the More menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the picture titled "Second"

There is an invisible scrollbar.

If you click and drag any of those sections downwards, then it will scroll, and you will see Groups appear. You can then tick it and it will appear under "More", and also as a section under "About"

Comment: If your answer answers your question, why don't you accept it?

Comment: @arieljannai  The site doesn't allow you to accept your own answer immediately and forces you to wait 2 days before doing so, so I forgot about it, but I have accepted it now.